# Where to find / create an image / iso suitable for anonymous browsing in a VM

Tags: linux, privacy, disk-image, kvm-switch

I'm looking for (as close as I can get) to a KVM or Virtualbox compatible system image I can run which will give me a basic desktop - by basic I mean contains only the  minimal requirements for a web browser designed to provide maximum anonymity - ideally based off Ubuntu or Redhat (or a derivative) with OpenVPN support baked in.

Is anyone aware of a place I can download popular "off-the-shelf" open source image (or images) designed for anonymous browsing ?   Ideally I'd like something I could set up and even modify by adding applications as required, but which does not save any information about me, and which will restore to only the basic image with added applications [but which does not retain any personal information or browsing history or cache]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this problem using [TAILS](https://tails.boum.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You might try Ipredia (http://www.ipredia.org)  or Privatix (http://www.mandalka.name/privatix/index.html.en) 
Both purport to be anonymous distros. Privatix is based off debian and has an openvpn package available.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could install Arch Linux and use [Tor](http://www.torproject.org). Security Onion is a Tor-enabled distro, I guess, but I have no experience with it. The first option seems better.